# "Map" and "Reduce" functions in Hadoop's MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've been looking at this word count example by hadoop: 
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred_tutorial.html#Source+Code

And I'm a little confused about the Map function. In the map function shown, it takes in a "key" of type LongWritable, but this parameter is never used in the body of the Map function. What does the application programmer expect Hadoop to pass in for this key? Why does a map function require a key if it simply parses values from a line of text or something. Can someone give me an example where both a key and a value is required for input? I only see map as V1 -> (K2, V2).

Another question: In the real implementation of hadoop, are their multiple reduction steps? If so, how does hadoop apply the same reduction function multiple times if the function is (K2, V2) -> (K3, V3)? If another reduction is performed, it needs to take in type (K3, V3)...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There's a key there because the map() method is always passed a key and a value (and a context).  It's up to you as to whether you actually use the key and/or value.  In this case, the key represents a line number from the file being read.  The word count logic doesn't need that.  The map() method just uses the value, which in the case of a text file is a line of the file.

As to your second question (which really should be its own stack overflow question), you may have any number of map/reduce jobs in a hadoop workflow.  Some of those jobs will read as input pre-existing files and others will read the output of other jobs.  Each job will have one or more mappers and a single reducer.

Comment: So if I get to declare the K1 as anything, how does Hadoop know what it should pass in as the key? Like in this case it may be a line number because its LongWritable, but if its something like String, does Hadoop know to pass something else in? Is it always line number?

Thanks..

Comment: It depends on the input format type you choose.  For file/text input types the kay/value is LongWritable/Text.  HDFS sequential files (another input format type) will have whatever key/value types you used when you created them.